# PrimeNG angular 2 CLI project Datepicker

Tags: angular, primeng

how to convert date to string using PrimeNG module angular in component.ts?

```
Argument of type 'Dateconstructor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'. Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'DateConstructor'
```

this is my script so far

component.ts

```
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {SearchLite} from '../room';
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

selected_date = Date;
  SearchLite = new SearchLite ( '',this.selected_date,'','',this.guest,this.room,'' );
}
```

Room.ts

```
export class SearchLite{
  constructor
  (
    public place:string,
    public date:Date,
    public duration_start:string,
    public duration_end:string,
    public guest:number,
    public room:number,
    public position:string
  ){}
}
```

component.html

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="selected_date" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" [inline]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: So, what have you [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please amend your question accordingly.

Comment: i need to get selected_date from CalendarModule thats appear in component.html

but i get error  `Argument of type 'Dateconstructor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Date'. Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'DateConstructor'`

Comment: You cannot convert date to a string using PrimeNG itself. Why don't you just take a look at your date format and convert it to string with plain javascript. Easy as that.